# Apply custom functions to sparse matrix in sklearn

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I'm working on a sentiment analysis project. I'm using bag of words on sklearn. I want to nomalize the rows as in:

```
a = [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
#a ->  4 non zero values
```

the normalized vector should be:

```
[0.25, 0.0, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.0, 0.25]
```

For b - > 8 non zeros values:

```
b = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

the normalized vector should be:

```
[0.125, 0.0, 0.125, 0.125, 0.0, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125]



class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix

  (0, 2111) 1
  (0, 2812) 1
  (0, 2848) 1
   ......
   ......
  (0, 5745) 1
  (0, 5823) 1
```

How can apply operations to such a matrix?

I know I can convert this to a regular matrix using the '.toarray' method, but this araise a memory issue, the matrix is several Gb.

Comment: This is not a solution but just a suggestion to overcome the memory issue. Since you are dealing with sparse matrix, you can store the matrix in Matrix Market format. Then you can normalize each value of the matrix in a very simple way like you are doing for a vector.

Comment: Have you looked at the methods of a csr matrix.  There's a sum, probably a mean. Make small array sparse and experiment.

Comment: I should add the `sklearn` has some custom sparse functions as well - to speed up common tasks in that package.  I've looked at their code for other questions, but haven't attention as to where or how they are documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sparse csr matrix has a `mean` method, the sparse version of `np.mean`:

```
In [2188]: a = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
In [2189]: a1 = sparse.csr_matrix(a)
In [2190]: a1
Out[2190]: 
<1x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Dense normalization:

```
In [2191]: np.mean(a)
Out[2191]: 0.40000000000000002
In [2192]: a/np.mean(a)
Out[2192]: array([ 2.5,  0. ,  2.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  2.5,  0. ,  2.5])
```

sparse normalization:

```
In [2193]: a1.mean()
Out[2193]: 0.40000000000000002
In [2194]: a1/a1.mean()
Out[2194]: 
<1x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [2195]: (a1/a1.mean()).A
Out[2195]: array([[ 2.5,  0. ,  2.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  2.5,  0. ,  2.5]])
```

As I just explained in the question about sparse dot product, numpy functions and methods have limited 'knowledge' of sparse matrices.  Familiarize yourself with the sparse methods and functions.  If those aren't enough then we can explore alternatives.